# Derivative Notation as a factor

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems, derivative, notation

In the figure below, from the book "Principles of Linear Systems and Signals - Lathi", the author uses the notation D to replace the Leibniz's notation $d/dt$, and after that he rewrites the equation, disconnecting the symbol of the derivative, $D$, of its function, considering each as a factor. I don't understand how he did that. Is that mathematically possible?

[image: derivative]

Comment: Can you add a link to the figure to your question?

Comment: I already upload the figure.

Comment: it's a sloppy abuse of notation that is equivalent to Laplace transformation of the linear differential equations (with the assumption of 0 initial conditions).  essentially "$D$" means "$s$" of the L.T. and Eq. (2.1b) should be $$ (s^N + a_1 s^{N-1} + ... + a_{N-1}s + a_N) Y(s) = (b_{N-M} s^M + b_{N-M+1} s^{M-1} + ... + b_{N-1} s + b_N) X(s) $$ and you would have polynomials $Q(s)$ and $P(s)$ and Eq. (2.1c) would be $$ Q(s)Y(s) = P(s)X(s) $$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, you're very mistaken. This is neither sloppy nor abusive. The theory of linear operators on vector spaces uses this notation very rigorously and consistently, and there are many upsides to it. It is also fully compatible with the usual notion of an operator or a matrix product in linear algebra.

Comment: listen @Jazzmaniac, it might have been 40 years ago, but i have had as much Functional Analysis (metric spaces, Banach spaces, Hilbert, etc.) as perhaps you. the "polynomials" $Q(D)$ and $P(D)$ are not polynomials in the pedantic sense. they are operators.  and they are definitely **not** multiplying $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ respectively. but transformed to the frequency domain, they **are** polynomials $Q(s)$ and $P(s)$, in the basic sense, and they **do** actually multiply $Y(s)$ and $X(s)$ which are not  $y(t)$ and $x(t)$, but directly related. i think that notation does little more than confuse.

Comment: You always have the last word @robertbristow-johnson, don't you? I studied mathematics, not engineering, so I doubt that you share my perspective. Mathematics is very comfortable with polynomials of linear operators, and those products are very well defined and as "real" as products between numbers. There's nothing fishy, misleading, sloppy, abusive or confusing about it. It's perfectly rigorous mathematics. But I know you enjoy leaning far out and uttering your opinion, so please keep going.

Comment: So which one of you guys is right? ;) @robertbristow-johnson or @Jazzmaniac?

Comment: it's a convention of notation.  if Jazz can hold a gun to my head and insist he's right, i'll say *"yeah, sure!"*.  all's i'm saying is that there is already existing a notation that converts the notation of the linear and homogeneous differential equation to a polynomial and we call that notation the *"Laplace Transform"*.  and it gets rid of $t$ and replaces  the independent variable with another symbol $s$.  i find that less confusing than the other.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the text, it's called *operational notation*, i.e. $D$ is an operator being applied to a continuous-time signal:

$$D^mx(t)=\frac{d^mx(t)}{dt^m}$$

In discrete time you have the operator $T$, defined by

$$T^mx[n]=x[n+m]$$

(see e.g. [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=uHs7gpNKqTEC&pg=PA499&lpg=PA499&dq=%22operational+notation%22+laplace&source=bl&ots=UJKodSOPLW&sig=l2jKC7n0r2iU9csc6TfYAAHU6Bs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ps4bVdeHMYO1OoykgYgM&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=operational&f=false)).

What is often done by people is that they use the complex Laplace transform variable $s$ instead of $D$, or the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform variable $z$ instead of $T$. This is what Robert Bristow-Johnson referred to in his comment as 'sloppy abuse of notation'. I would even go further and would call it simply wrong. The use of different letters for $D$ and $T$ may seem an unimportant triviality, but the real problem here is that you mix different domains (Laplace/$\mathcal{Z}$ transform domain and time domain), which can be a great source of misunderstandings and errors.

I personally do not see a great advantage in the use of this type of operational notation for engineering applications. It rather makes things more confusing for beginners because they have a tendency to mix domains anyway, and operational notation seems to suggest that this is legitimate.